# WPF VB.net Listview How can I display the Value of the Selected Cell

Tags: wpf, vb.net, listview, data-binding

first of all, I'm new in programming with WPF and I have some difficults with the listview in WPF.
I already have a ObservableCollection and want to display the value of the selected Cell in a MsgBox.

My Question is, how should I do that ?

This doesn't work for me:

```
mylistview.SelectedItem()
```

My Code:

## XAML

```
<ListView x:Name="mylistView" Margin="10,31,10,149.714" SelectionMode="Multiple" ItemsSource="{Binding}" Grid.ColumnSpan="3" Background="#FFA4A4A4" BorderThickness="2" BorderBrush="#FF6A6F77">
    <ListView.View>
        <GridView>
            <GridViewColumn DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path=Track}" Width="100" Header="Track"/>
            <GridViewColumn Width="auto" Header="" >
                <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <Image Width="50" Height="50" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Source="{Binding Path=Image}"/>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
            </GridViewColumn>
            <GridViewColumn DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path=Endung}" Width="100" Header=" Container"/>
            <GridViewColumn DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path=Album}" Width="100" Header="Album"/>
            <GridViewColumn DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path=Bitrate}" Width="100" Header="Bitrate"/>
            <GridViewColumn DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path=Pfad}" Width="100" Header="Pfad"/>
        </GridView>
    </ListView.View>
</ListView>
```

## Code-Behind

```
Dim files As New ObservableCollection(Of Austauscher) 

    Public Structure Austauscher
    Private _track As String
    Private _album As String
    Private _pfad As String
    Private _bitrate As String
    Private _endung As String
    Private _image As BitmapImage

    Property Track() As String
        Get
            Return _track
        End Get
        Set(ByVal Value As String)
            _track = Value
        End Set
    End Property
    Property Album() As String
        Get
            Return _album
        End Get
        Set(ByVal Value As String)
            _album = Value
        End Set
    End Property
    Public Property Pfad As String
        Get
            Return _pfad
        End Get
        Set(ByVal Value As String)
            _pfad = Value
        End Set
    End Property
    Property Bitrate As String
        Get
            Return _bitrate
        End Get
        Set(ByVal Value As String)
            _bitrate = Value
        End Set
    End Property
    Property Endung As String
        Get
            Return _endung
        End Get
        Set(ByVal Value As String)
            _endung = Value
        End Set
    End Property
    Property Image As BitmapImage
        Get
            Return _image
        End Get
        Set(ByVal Value As BitmapImage)
            _image = Value
        End Set
    End Property

End Structure
```

And I add files with:

```
files.Add(New Austauscher With {.Track = "Track", .Pfad = path, .Album = "Album", .Bitrate = "kbs", .Endung = "extension"})
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is with the listView, as you have discovered it lacks a "selectedCell" property.

You may find you can get the functionality you require by using the [datagrid](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.datagrid(v=vs.110).aspx) control, I have made a version that should work in the same way as your listview example;

```
        <DataGrid Name="myGridView"  SelectionMode="Extended" SelectionUnit="Cell" ItemsSource="{Binding}" Grid.ColumnSpan="3" Background="#FFA4A4A4" BorderThickness="2" BorderBrush="#FF6A6F77" AutoGenerateColumns="False">
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Track" Binding="{Binding Path=Track}" Width="100"/>
        <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="">
            <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <Image Width="50" Height="50" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Source="{Binding Path=Image}"/>
                </DataTemplate>
            </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
        </DataGridTemplateColumn>
        <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Path=Endung}" Width="100" Header=" Container"/>
        <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Path=Album}" Width="100" Header="Album"/>
        <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Path=Bitrate}" Width="100" Header="Bitrate"/>
        <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Path=Pfad}" Width="100" Header="Pfad"/>
    </DataGrid>
```

The datagrid offers more control over your selections and contains a property called selectedCells, it is a collection because (as in your example) you can select many cells. If you want to have only one selected cell then you should set the SelectionMode property to single (allowing you to select only a single item and set the SelectionUnit (as in my example) to Cell. Alternitively you can use the CurrentCell property that returns the the cell that has focus;

```
myGridView.CurrentCell
```

I hope this helps.